# Insert Multiple Rows into Table from a Table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures, insert

I have a SQL Server 2008 database. The database has a stored procedure which receives two strings as parameters. One parameter is used to build a temp table which will usually only have 1 or 2 rows but theoretically could have more.

For each row in the temp table, I need to insert a row into a different table that consists of the other parameter and the contents of the temp table. Is there a way to do this without a cursor?

I've tried variations on the following:

Pseudo code:

```
procedure InsertLinks(@Key varchar(36), @LinkKey varchar(36)

tempLinks Table = getLinks(@LinkKey)

Insert into MyTable (Key, LinksTo) Values (@Key, Select LinksTo From tempLinks)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `VALUES` clause is messed up - you have a single value comma a table. That's not valid.

The following should work just fine:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable (Key, LinksTo) 
SELECT @Key, LinksTo 
FROM tempLinks
```

Comment: Thanks! Should have seen that, I've done similar with Update queries. Don't know why I was getting a brain cramp on that.